InstallShield Registry
Need to use a dynamic parameter in a registry entry to specify a dll file location.
In the example below the parameter  is the path to the folder where the dll is installed by InstallShield:
"CodeBase"="file://///"
So far we always had the  as a fixed location.  Now it is changed based on the install directory location - a parameter InstallShield gets from the user during installation.

The example should have been:

The example should have been:  "CodeBase"="file://///.dll" -- the parameter  is the path to the folder where the dll is installed by InstallShield:

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
